# Como criar um icon com hover animado

Tags: javascript, css

o que eu preciso saber para criar um hover animado como este no menu http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/? Eu sei que este menu é feito com javascript, mas aonde eu devo procurar esse tais icons que parecem gifs, algum site ou font especifico, ou eu teria que criar-los? Alguém pode me mostrar um exemplo simples, de um icon de como eu deveria me guiar e criar o resto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode encontrar ícones deste tipo em [Metro Icon Font](http://metroui.org.ua/font.html), na [página inicial](http://metroui.org.ua/) do framework você pode baixá-lo assim como pegar os ícones separadamente, e nele tem as instruções de como utilizar.

Você pode também estar fazendo animações com ícones através do CSS, até com DIV, elementos da página etc...

Para isto você deve utilizar o parâmetro **animation** do css.

**Exemplo**

```
.animar-algo {
    animation: ani-ring 2s ease infinite;
}
```

Neste caso o elemento que você aplicar este CSS, vai ficar balançando como um sino sem parar. Para adicionar o efeitos apenas quando o mouse passar por cima, utilize o *hover*.

`.animar-algo:hover`

A ordem que eu utilizei é a seguinte:

`ani-ring` `2s` `ease` `infinite`

`nome do efeito` `tempo de duração` `função da cronometragem`

> **infinite** é para que o efeito seja infinito e não pare

Tem mais exemplos no [Metro Icon Font](http://metroui.org.ua/font.html) lá no final da página tem mais exemplos que você pode estar **inspecionando elemento** para ver como se faz o efeito.

Answer (score 0):

Veja [aqui](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/) o Hover.css. É um pacote de vários icones com esse efeito.

Baixe o pacote que ele tem as instruções de como usar, é bem simples.